# Leer y cambiar linea de ficheros en diferentes carpetas

Tags: java, archivo

Voy a intentar explicar lo que busco de manera sencilla y breve.

Teniendo en cuenta la siguiente estructura de carpetas.

```
carpetaPrincipal -> carpeta1 y carperta2
```

Dentro de `carpeta1` y `carpeta2` hay un archivo llamado `texto.txt`, el cual contiene la linea -> `version=2.0`

Lo que busco implementar es leer todas las carpetas que tenga `carpetaPrincipal` y a su vez, leer los archivos que contengan dichas carpetas y cambiar el texto de `version=2.0` a `version=3.8`

No se si sera muy difícil hacer esto. Aun no tengo nada pero había pensado en utilizar `BufferedReader` y `FileReader`. Guardar en `Strings` el nombre de la ruta en cuestion y el nombre del archivo a buscar junto a la linea a cambiar.

Espero que puedan guiarme un poco.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Empezando por que no tengo unos conocimientos muy amplios, mi idea seria hacer algun tipo de iterador. Tambien podria mirar de utilizar Apache POI para la edicion de los ficheros.

Comment: Por favor comparte el código de lo que has intentado. Saludos.

Comment: @IvánMontero usar POI para txt es matar moscas a cañonazos.